# PYTHON: enter the number of days after today for a future day and display the future day of the week

Tags: python

I figured out how to code todays date but i am having trouble finding out how to code the future date, if the future date is larger than the integer 6. In the textbook they entered todays date is 0 so it is Sunday. But for days elapsed since Sunday, they entered 31. The result was "Today is Sunday and the future day is Wednesday". I do not understand how this was coded. This is what I have so far.

```
todaysDate = eval(input("Enter an interger for today's day of the week from 0 - 6, Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6."))


if todaysDate == 0:
    print("Today is Sunday")
elif todaysDate == 1:
    print("Today is Monday")
elif todaysDate == 2:
    print("Today is Tuesday")
elif todaysDate == 3:
    print("Today is Wednesday")
elif todaysDate == 4:
    print("Today is Thursday")
elif todaysDate == 5:
    print("Today is Friday")
elif todaysDate == 6:
    print("Today is Saturday")



daysElapsed = eval(input("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:"))

if daysElapsed == 1:
    print("Today is Sunday and the future day is Monday")
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

here the `(daysElapsed+todaysDate) % 7` gives you the value of future day

```
def future(day):
    if day == 0:
        print("future is Sunday")
    elif day == 1:
        print("future is Monday")
    elif day == 2:
        print("future is Tuesday")
    elif day == 3:
        print("future is Wednesday")
    elif day == 4:
        print("future is Thursday")
    elif day == 5:
        print("future is Friday")
    elif day == 6:
        print("future is Saturday")

todaysDate = int(input("Enter an interger for today's day of the week from 0 - 6, Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6."))


if todaysDate == 0:    
    print("Today is Sunday")
elif todaysDate == 1:
    print("Today is Monday")
elif todaysDate == 2:
    print("Today is Tuesday")
elif todaysDate == 3:
    print("Today is Wednesday")
elif todaysDate == 4:
    print("Today is Thursday")
elif todaysDate == 5:
    print("Today is Friday")
elif todaysDate == 6:
    print("Today is Saturday")


daysElapsed = int(input("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:"))
future((daysElapsed+todaysDate) % 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator, `%`, to divide by 7 and return the remainder of that operation:

```
>>> 0 % 7
0
>>> 5 % 7
5
>>> 7 % 7
0
>>> 10 % 7
3
```

Also, use `int()` instead of `eval()` to cast the user's input as an integer. It's much safer.

You can put this together with a `list` to hold the values instead of a large `if` block:

```
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

today = int(input("Enter an interger for today's day of the week from 0 - 6, Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6."))
future = int(input("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:"))
print('Today is {} and the future day is {}.'.format(days[today],
                                                     days[(today+future)%7]))
```

Comment: Hi @TigerhawkT3, I dont quite understand the modulus operator, could you explain why 5 % 7 is 5 and so on? Thank you

Comment: @DandyPotato - As mentioned, it performs an ordinary division operator and then gives you the remainder. Five divided by seven is zero, remainder five.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tigerhawk's answer (Would comment but not enough rep :()

You could minimise the code repeition by storing the days in a list and accessing them as such:

```
days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

todaysDate = int(input("Enter an interger for today's day of the week from 0 - 6, Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6."))
print "Today is {}".format(days[todaysDate])

daysElapsed = int(input("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:"))
print "Today is Sunday and the future day is {}".format(days[daysElapsed % 7])
```

Definitely don't use eval, because every time someone writes it on SO, it gets bashed ;) Oh and its unsafe or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
  d = {0:"Saturday",1:"Sunday",2:"Monday",3:"Tuesday",4:"Wednesday",5:"Thursday",6:"Friday"}

    n = int(input("Enter today's day number : "))

    w = int(input("Enter the number of days after today : "))

    s = n+w

if s<=6 and s>0:

print("Today is",d[n],"and the future day is",d[n])

    elif s>6:

print("Today is",d[n],"and the future day is",d[s%7])
```